# Calling a method form a mobile application

Tags: php, url, methods, http-post

I'm new with PHP.
In my mobile application I have to query some data form server.
I have to call login before i can access the data.
I have to use the following type of Post request

```
http://SERVER_IP/wapdb/smartphone_login/
```

How it can be done in my PHP file?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should  detect the mobile device after the login so the webpage/mobile application uses styling that would work for maybe the desktop and mobile but when you login, it logs in the same way you would on a desktop using PHP, after you login, you could then change the page contents by the resolution of the phone. Otherwise you end up having two potentially dangerous logins that are basically the same but different folders.

In the form you will have used the method post, so the PHP script will use an array called $_POST and can use it by the name of the input elements for example (example in HTML):

```
<form method='POST' action='test.php'>
    <input name='first_name'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'/>
</form>
```

In PHP you can then do whatever you want by reading the contents of the post array

```
<?php
     echo "Your name is " . $_POST['first_name'];
?>
```

You can use a php file to add the server IP in a  tag.

```
<?php echo "<form method='POST' action='http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . "/wapdb/login/'><input name='first_name'/><input type='submit' value='Send'/></form>"; ?>
```

I would recommend you to have a play with $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] and other variables from http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php since it might use the internal IP address and you'd want the public IP. You can also look at some information available at W3Schools. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Hope this helps.